# Puppeteer: How get img src inside nested selector?

Tags: javascript, image, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have a structure like this:

```html
<div class="loaded active">
<img class="full" src="img1.jpg">
</div>

<div class="loaded">
<img class="full" src="img2.jpg">
</div>

<div class="loaded">
<img class="full" src="img3.jpg">
</div>
```

I need get link of img1.jpg.
I can get links for class="full":

```js
const slkImg = '.full';
    
const imgs = await page.$$eval(slkImg, postLinks => postLinks.map(link => link.src));
```

but I don't know how do it for only img1.jpg.

Comment: Is `page.$eval('.full', el => el.src);` what you're looking for? Or is it the `.active` class you're after, so `page.$eval('.loaded.active .full', el => el.src);`? Or `page.$$eval(".loaded.active .full", els => els.map(el => el.src));` if there are multiple?

Comment: Thank you for help! It turned out to be very simple, but I did not think of it: `.loaded.active .full`, about space.

`page.$eval('.loaded.active .full', el => el.src);` work as i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments,

```js
page.$eval('.loaded.active .full', el => el.src)
```

works thanks to two things:

1. Using `$eval` rather than `$$eval` to select one element
2. Using `.loaded.active .full` to select the first `.full` descendent of the first `.loading.active` parent.